# getting a number instead of field name when i use want distinct values with its count

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am very new to Django

I have table Category which contains category

```
class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
```

and also table "Post" which uses "Category" table as foreign key

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

but using below query what i get is

```
Post.objects.values('category').order_by('category').annotate(the_count=Count('category'))
```

result

```
<QuerySet [{'category': 2, 'the_count': 5}, {'category': 3, 'the_count': 4}]>
```

what i want is

```
<QuerySet [{'category': "fashion", 'the_count': 5}, {'category': "travel", 'the_count': 4}]>
```

how do i fix this problem

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the field in your query and then access those "values" on the template.

views.py

```py
posts = Post.objects.values('category__category').order_by('category').annotate(the_count=Count('category'))
```

template.html

```html
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.category__category }} - {{ post.the_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Rossata Thanks , it worked , i know it was i silly question but i couldn't figure out on my own .Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad it worked @young_minds1. I'd be nice of you if you can mark my answer as correct then. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi , can you please help me on this , now i have result <QuerySet [{'category__category': 'Travel', 'the_count': 5}, {'category__category': 'Others', 'the_count': 4}]>  , how to i  show category and its count in template,i tried doing with for loop but values didn't show up

Comment: I've edited my answer @young_minds1. Hopefully, that'd help.

Comment: Thanks i got it.:-) @Higor